# Is the projective symmetry group of a polytope more general than its linear symmetry group?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, projective-geometry, symmetry

Give a (convex) polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ (the convex hull of finitely many points). Consider its linear and projective symmetry groups:

\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PGL}{PGL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\OO}{O}
\Aut_{\GL}(P)&:=\{T\in\GL(\Bbb R^d)\mid TP=P\}\subseteq\GL(\Bbb R^d),\\
\Aut_{\PGL}(P)&:=\{T\in\PGL(\Bbb R^d)\mid TP=P\}\subseteq\PGL(\Bbb R^d).
\end{align}

Clearly, $\Aut_{\GL}(P)\subseteq \Aut_{\PGL}(P)$, but we do not necessarily have equality.

> **Question:** Is there always a transformation $T\in\PGL(\Bbb R^d)$ so that $\Aut_{\GL}(TP)=\Aut_{\PGL}(TP)$?

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

As pointed out by Guillaume, I should exclude the case when $P$ is a simplex, since then $\smash{\Aut_{\PGL}(P)}$ is infinite. Alterantively, my intention is to consider two symmetries the same if they induce the same permutation on the vertices of the polyope.

---

Note that the answer is *No* if we consider finite sets of points rather than polytopes, because the projective symmetry group of any $d+2$ points in $\smash{\Bbb R^d}$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $\mathrm{Sym}(d+2)$, which is not possible with just linear symmetries.

The question is motivated from the well-known fact that the linear symmetries of a polytopes $P$ are not more general than its orthogonal symmetries, in the sense that there always is a transformation $\smash{T\in\GL(\Bbb R^d)}$ with $\smash{\Aut_{\OO}(TP)=\Aut_{\GL}(TP)}$.

Comment: This seems to fail for a triangle, since the affine symmetry group is finite but the projective symmetry group is infinite.

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun Am I assuming a non-standard way to talk about projective symmetries? If two symmetries (affine or projective) permute the vertices in the same way then it is the same symmetry, isn't it?

Comment: The issue I point is even more transparent in dimension $1$. The map $x \mapsto \frac{x}{2-x}$ belongs to the projective symmetry group of the polytope $[0,1]$ ; its action on vertices is the same as the identity map $x \mapsto x$. Do you want to consider these maps as the same? You may want to assume that your polytope is not a simplex.